# sequence of actions in the logical expression

Tags: java, logical-operators

I want to ask about correct sequence "reading" of this logical expression:

```
(true && false | true)
```

I thought it returns false, because of first expression -  `true && false`  
But probably I'm doing something wrong and it's should be "reading" another way.
Can you explain what's correct way to reading it?

Comment: | operator has higher precedence than && operator. false | true became true and then true && true is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping below the point in the notice:

**All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.**

This will be get executed from left to right. After that 2nd point to consider is **Operator Precedence**.

| is a bitwise operator and && is a logical operation. the bitwise operator has more priority than the logical operator.

In your case, the first evaluation will be false | true which is true.

then it will evaluate the true && result of above which is true.

so the given statement will be true.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following table of [Operators Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

`|` (bitwise inclusive OR) has higher precedence than `&&` (logical AND), so `false | true` is evaluated first.

That said, the evaluation order doesn't matter in your example. Both `(true && false) | true` and `true && (false | true)` return `true`. In the first case it's `false | true)`, which is `true`. In the second case it's `true && true`, which is also `true`.

Now, here's an example where the operator precedence makes a difference:

```
System.out.println (false && true | true);
System.out.println (false && true || true);
```

`|` has a higher precedence than `&&`, but `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.

Therefore these expressions are evaluated as:

```
System.out.println (false && (true | true));
System.out.println ((false && true) || true);
```

As a result, the first returns `false` and the second returns `true`.